# pythonにある「ローカル変数」とはなんですか？具体的に教えてください。

Tags: python

僕はまだpythonを始めたばかりでローカル変数というものをまだよくわかりません。
そのため、具体的に知っている人は教えていただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 質問の方も具体的にしてもらった方がいいと思います。例えば、これこれこういうケース（コードの中）でローカル変数というものが登場したが、これはどういうことなのですか？　といった風に。

Answer (score 4):

**大雑把で短い説明**：たとえば関数を定義するときに、その関数の中では参照できるが関数の外では参照できなくなる変数を、「関数ローカルの変数」という意味を込めて「ローカル変数」と呼びます。

具体的には、以下のプログラムを書いたときに、変数 `a` は関数 `piyo` の外でも参照できますが、変数 `b` は関数 `piyo` の外では参照できなくなります。

```py
a = 42

def piyo():
    b = 100
    print(a + b)

print(a)  # これは大丈夫

print(b)  # これは「b が定義されていない」というエラーになります。
```

この仕組みを使うことによって、変数を「使える区間」が整理され、プログラムの読み書きが少し簡単になります。

より詳しくは、Python のチュートリアルとなるような書籍やウェブサイトが世の中にはたくさんあるので、そういったものを読むのが良いでしょう。一問一答形式で解決していくよりも、体系的に教えてくれる資料を読む方が早いように思います。